# datatool: getting a specific value given the value of another column

Tags: datatool

I am certain this is patently obvious, but the solution is eluding me...

Given a dataset stored in CSV:

```
ID,    col1,  col2, col3
KEY-1, foo    bar,  baz
KEY-2, alice, bob,  chuck
```

I would like to define a macro `\getCol3{KEY-2}` that returns `chuck`. I am getting tripped up by what appears to be internal key structures (and the fact that I just started using `datatool`).

```
\DTLgetvalue{\thevalue}{data}{\therow}{\thecol}
```

is what I assumed was in the right direction, but I cannot construct valid values for `\therow` and `\thevalue`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `\DTLgetvalueforkey`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.csv}
ID,    col1,  col2, col3
KEY-1, foo,   bar,  baz
KEY-2, alice, bob,  chuck
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{demo.csv}
\newcommand*{\thevalue}{}
\newcommand*{\getCol}[2]{%
  \DTLgetvalueforkey{\thevalue}{col#1}{data}{ID}{#2}%
}
\getCol{3}{KEY-2}
\show\thevalue
```

Here, we are using `ID` as the *reference key* to find the appropriate row, which is found using the argument `#2`.

Comment: of course, i was missing `\newcommand*{\thevalue}{}` ... i knew is was something simple. thanks!