# Overhanging vertical bars in tabular

Tags: tables, automation, datatool

My question stems from an adaptation of the solution shown here :
[Generating lists and tables of items from commands in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137504/generating-lists-and-tables-of-items-from-commands-in-the-document)

The idea is to sum up the reviews of a given document in a table.
Since the table is on the front page of a whole series of document, I was looking for a way to automatize it.

In my document class :

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\DTLnewdb{docreview}

\newcommand{\review}[6]{%
  \DTLnewrow{docreview}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Date}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Redacteur}{#2}% 
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Verificateur}{#3}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Approbateur}{#4}%   
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Modification}{#5}%    
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Indice}{#6}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  [...]
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    Date &  Redacteur &  Verificateur &  Approbateur & Visa de l'approbateur &  Modification & Indice \\ \hline\hline
    \DTLforeach{docreview}{%
    \Date=Date,\Redacteur=Redacteur,\Verificateur=Verificateur,\Approbateur=Approbateur,\Modification=Modification, \Indice=Indice}{%
    \Date & \Redacteur & \Verificateur & \Approbateur & & \Modification & \Indice \\\hline} 
  \end{tabular}
}
```

In my document itself :

```
\begin{document}
\review{1 janvier 1970}{Me}{Verif.}{Approb.}{Epoch}{0}
\review{22 avril 2019}{Me}{Verif.}{Approb.}{Mod.}{0}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

That solution works like a charm except for a detail which I can't figure out.
The generated table shows the two first vertical bar (1st column limits) and only these that continues an additional row...

[image: pdf output]

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last `\\\hline` shouldn't be inside the the loop but after it, so that the code of the loop doesn't triggers the creation of a new row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\DTLnewdb{docreview}

\newcommand{\review}[6]{%
  \DTLnewrow{docreview}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Date}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Redacteur}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Verificateur}{#3}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Approbateur}{#4}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Modification}{#5}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docreview}{Indice}{#6}%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  [...]


  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    Date &  Redacteur &  Verificateur &  Approbateur & Visa de l'approbateur &  Modification & Indice \\ \hline\hline
    \DTLforeach{docreview}{%
    \Date=Date,\Redacteur=Redacteur,\Verificateur=Verificateur,\Approbateur=Approbateur,\Modification=Modification, \Indice=Indice}{%
    \Date & \Redacteur & \Verificateur & \Approbateur & & \Modification & \Indice
   \DTLiflastrow{}{\\\hline}} %<-------
    \\\hline %<---------
  \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
\review{1 janvier 1970}{Me}{Verif.}{Approb.}{Epoch}{0}
\review{22 avril 2019}{Me}{Verif.}{Approb.}{Mod.}{0}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```