# How can I create a small "database" of objects in my LaTeX project and use different subsets of their properties at different places

Tags: bibliographies, packages, glossaries

Suppose you want to maintain a set of objects in a central place and render them differently (``views'') at various places in your LaTeX document, similar to glossaries but more generic.

For example, consider you want to setup a small "database" of employees with their first names, last names, identifier, date of birth etc.
Then you want to create a list of employees in the introduction section of the document, where only the first names are printed, separated by comma. In the appendix, however, you want to print a table that shows all properties (as columns) and all employees (as rows).

Also, you want to be able to ``pick'' single entries from this database in different formats, similar to \Glspl{employee1}, \gls{employee1}, ...

Of course, one method could be to use e.g. a combination of scripting and sqlite to generate latex code as a preprocessing step.

However, what would be the most straightforward LaTeXish way to do this? Are there any packages that could help here?

Comment: Too abstract. I think the answer would be "learn some TeX programming then the solution would essentially be straightforward", but not much more can be said.

Comment: (but TeX is a terrible programming language so easier option includes using e.g. PythonTeX, LuaTeX,PerlTeX etc.)

Comment: Have a look at biber - it can do more than just bibliographies.

Comment: ... or the datatool package

Comment: I agree, this sounds more or less like object-oriented programming, so why not simply use Lua which supports this out of the box?

Comment: it depends a bit on the numbers. A small set can be done with expl3 properties or datatool (both load all data in memory). With biblatex you can store more entries in an external bib-file.

Comment: As an example of the datatool approach see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137504/generating-lists-and-tables-of-items-from-commands-in-the-document/137598 which shows most of the features you are asking about I think.

Answer (score 0):

As said on the comments, to manipulate big amounts of data, there are better programming languages that can be used together with LaTeX. One of this alternatives is `knitr` (an R package) that allow mix R and LaTeX code.

To test the example below, you should save it with the `.Rnw` extension and you can compile it with Rstudio,or see [How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line). If you have not R in your computer, also in Overleaf you probably test this file, but using the extension`.Rtex`.

The MWE:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
% preample only to beautify the result, nothing is essential 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\belowcaptionskip{1ex}

\begin{document}

\section*{The raw data for this example}

 
<<employees,echo=FALSE>>=
# construct a data frame (you can also import it csv, excel, csv, ...)
  df <- data.frame(
    Name    = c("Bob", "Sam",  "Jim"),
    Surname = c("Wood","Smith","Carter"),
    Rate = c(94,     4,     3), # Field experience (%)
    date = as.Date(c('1990-10-02','1981-3-24','1987-6-14')),
    Position= c("director","subdirector","secretary"))
# Nicknames as ID   
rownames(df) <- c("nba", "spy",  "tv") 

today <- as.Date(Sys.Date())

# Show raw data
    df
@

\section*{About our fake employees}

The team will be our employees 
\Sexpr{combine_words(paste(df$Name,df$Surname))}.

Although the mean rate experience of the team is only 
\Sexpr{round(mean(df$Rate),1)}\;\%, but the \Sexpr{df[1,5]} of the project will be \Sexpr{df[1,1]}. Mr. \Sexpr{df["nba",2]} 
is highly cualified for this specific work 
(\Sexpr{df["nba","Rate"]}\;\%). 
He was born in 
\Sexpr{format(df["nba","date"], format = "%Y")}, 
so roughly he has now 
\Sexpr{format(difftime(today, df["nba","date"], 
    unit="days"), big.mark = '\\\\;')} 
days of living experience. 

\section*{Full team data (to show)}

See in table \ref{Team}: 

<<team table,echo=F, results="asis">>=
library(xtable)
    
df$date <-  as.character(df$date)     
print(xtable(df[,c(1,2,5,4,3)], 
             caption="Full team",
             label="Team",
             align="llllcr",
             digits=0),
      booktabs=T,
      include.rownames=F,
      caption.placement="top"
      )

@

\end{document}
```